# ISO C++ forbids initialisation of private const unsigned long?

Tags: c++, codepad

I'm using codepad.org

```
class a {
    private:
        const unsigned long b = 100;
};
```

> Line 3: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'b'
>
> compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Sorry if I've missed something obvious, but what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have the relevant C++11 support switched on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before C++11, you can only initialise a static const data member in the class definition:

```
static const unsigned long b = 100;
```

This is usually what you want anyway. It doesn't make much sense to have all instances of `a` have this constant value duplicated among them.

If you enable C++11 support, [your code will compile](http://ideone.com/8hBBnA).

Answer (score 1):

In-class initialization is only allowed for `static` `const` integral types in C++03, and your variable isn't `static`.

Either make it `static` (in this case, you should - note that you also have to define it in this casee), or use a C++11 compiler.